# Python Putting List within List when I only want one list

Tags: python, sql, python-2.7, python-3.x

Im fetching a row from a table that has multiple values delimited by a ";". I'm trying to store it within a list. Everything works but instead of python printing it as just ['a','b','c']... it is printing it as [['a','b','c']].

Code below

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Main_Setup");
rows = cur.fetchall()

job1= []
job2=[]

for row in rows:
    name = row[1]
    fields = row[4].split(';')
    if name == 'File1':
        job1.append(fields)

    elif name == 'file2':
        job2.append(fields)
```

Output:

```
[['this field', '   another field']]
[['haha', 'no', '  yes']]
```

Desired Output:

```
['this field', '   another field']
['haha', 'no', '  yes']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then instead of using `append` use `extend`. Like so:

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Main_Setup");
rows = cur.fetchall()

job1= []
job2=[]

for row in rows:
    name = row[1]
    fields = row[4].split(';')
    if name == 'File1':
        job1.extend(fields)

    elif name == 'file2':
        job2.extend(fields)
```

That is a bit curious though because I thought queries return `tuple`s, not `list`s (so your output should be `[('this field', '   another field')]`). But `extend` works nonetheless.

Comment: Thank YOU!. Worked like a charm.